# Output common array elements

Tags: arrays, perl, compare

I have a line saved in a text document which I read into an array. The line is

```
John is the uncle of Sam
```

I have another array that contains the words `aunt`, `uncle` and `father`. I would like both the arrays to compare and output the uncle (case insensitive). I don't know what I am doing wrong. I used [List::Compare](https://metacpan.org/module/List::Compare), [Array::Utils qw(:all)](https://metacpan.org/module/Array::Utils) etc. Could someone give me a working code.  I just need the comparison part.

This is all I have done so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Array::Utils qw':all';

print "Please enter the name of the file\n";
my $c = <STDIN>;
chomp($c);

open(NEW,$c) or die "The file cannot be opened";

my @d = <NEW>;


my @g = qw'aunt uncle father';
chomp(@g);
chomp(@d);

my @isect = intersect(@g, @d);
print @isect;
```

Comment: Suppose the whole code is here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057211/perl-read-a-file-and-an-array-and-find-common-words/)

Comment: yeah. that whole thing only makes it confusing which is why I split it.

Comment: Please use 3-arg [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html "perldoc -f open") `open(NEW,'<',$c)`. You should also think about using lexical file handles `open( my $new_fh, '<', $c )` `my @d = <$new_fh>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one array that contains 3 elements (aunt uncle sister) and the one that you read from the file only contains one (! "John is the uncle of Sam"):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @searchwords = qw(aunt uncle sister);
my @article = ("John is the uncle of Sam",);

foreach my $searchword (@searchwords){
    my $pattern = quotemeta $searchword;

    foreach my $line (@article){
        if ($line =~ /$pattern/i){  
            # //i makes the match case insensitive
            print $searchword . " matched in " . $line . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to have every word of that line in an array you should use `split` on the line like in `@words_from_line = split(" ",$line);` Then you get an array with words which you can compare to the other one.

Answer (score 2):

At its simplest:

```
for my $line (@file) {
    for my $word (@words) {
        if ($line =~ /\Q$word/i) {
            print "$word is found in '$line'";
        }
    }
}
```

You can merge the words into a regex, which will allow you to skip the looping over words:

```
my $rx = join '|', map quotemeta, @words;
for my $line (@file) {
    if ($line =~ /$rx/i) {
        print "Match found";
    }
}
```

Or using `grep`:

```
my @found = grep /$rx/i, @file;
```